# Angular 6 [(ngModel)] in view not changing variable in component

Tags: data-binding, angular6, angular-components, ngmodel

I have a `ClientModule` module separate from the main `AppModule`.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { ClientsRoutingModule } from './clients-routing.module';
import { ClientsListComponent } from './clients-list/clients-list.component';
import { ClientAddComponent } from './client-add/client-add.component';
import { ClientDetailComponent } from './client-detail/client-detail.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ClientsRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [ClientsListComponent, ClientAddComponent, ClientDetailComponent]
})
export class ClientsModule { }
```

I have `FormsModule` imported on `AppModule`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I am trying to bind input fields from view to the following component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ClientModel } from '../client.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-client-add',
  templateUrl: './client-add.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./client-add.component.scss']
})
export class ClientAddComponent implements OnInit {
  fname: string;
  lname: string;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  createClient() {
    console.log(this.fname, this.lname);
  }
}
```

And following is my view

```
<div class="card-body">
        <form class="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">First Name {{fname}}</label>
            <input type="text" ([ngModel]) = "fname" class="form-control rounded-0" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" ([ngModel]) = "lname" class="form-control rounded-0">
          </div>

          <button type="button" (click)="createClient()" class="btn btn-success float-center">Create New Client</button>
        </form>
      </div>
```

When I click the `Create New Client` button, the resultant log is `undefined undefined`
What am I doing wrong? I have spent a lot of time tackling this issue/bug in my code but so far its no good. Please help.

And this may be unrelated but I followed angular.io guide on lazy-loading of modules, where it mentions I should see an incoming `chunk` file while lazy-loading is happening in network tab but I don't. Maybe it has something to do with it?

**EDIT**
I also tried importing `FormsModule` in in `ClientsModule`. Problem persists.

**EDIT**
However, `[(ngModel)]` works as expected in `app.component.ts` of `AppModule`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad.

In my view `ngModel` should be a banana in the box `[(ngModel)]` but I mistyped as a box in the banana `([])`.